# "drei- oder viermal" oder "drei oder vier Male"?

Tags: usage

Normalerweise sagt man zum Beispiel

> (a) Ich habe mir diesen Film dreimal angesehen.

Wenn man ein bisschen Unsicherheit ausdrücken möchte, kann man sagen/schreiben

> (b) Ich habe mir diesen Film drei- oder viermal angesehen.

(und zwar, mit dem Strich)?

Kann man auch sagen

> (c) Ich habe mir diesen Film drei oder vier Male angesehen.

? In [Canoo](http://www.canoonet.eu/spelling/mal:N) kommt diese Verwendung nicht vor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deine Formen sind alle möglich, üblicher sind aber diese:

> Ich habe mir den Fim drei oder vier Mal angesehen.

Oder

> Ich habe mir den Film mehrere Male angesehen.

Die letzte Form, bzw. grundsätzlich die Pluralform "Male" ist aber zumindest angestaubt und tönt alt. Ich würde sie in der Umgangssprache nicht mehr verwenden.

Comment: Tendenziell gebe ich Dir recht, aber gerade "mehrere Male" empfinde ich auch gesprochen nicht als steif. Hingegen würde ich "viele Male" eher schreiben als sagen.